# How to check for clipboard update? Pywin32

Tags: python, clipboard, pywin32

## The problem

I am using the [win32clipboard](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32clipboard.html) module from [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/). I am trying to check for clipboard updates when they happen. I currently have a working solution but I am not sure it is the most effective and resourced managed.

### Non-Optimal solution

I have used a while true loop to constantly check the clipboard and print the content to the terminal.

```py
import win32clipboard as clipboard
from PIL import ImageGrab
import threading
import time

def listener():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        if clipboard.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(clipboard.CF_TEXT):
            text = clipboard.GetClipboardData()
            print(text)
        if clipboard.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(clipboard.CF_BITMAP):
            im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
            im.save("clipboard_image.png")
            print("image")
        clipboard.CloseClipboard()

clipboardListener = threading.Thread(target=listener())
clipboardListener.start()
```

This is surely not the best solution and there must be a more efficient one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider some kind of flag using "win32clipboard.GetClipboard SequenceNumber()" function.

You can use this code in the function description.

```
import win32clipboard as clipboard
clip_int = clipboard.GetClipboardSequenceNumber()
print(clip_int) #Clipboard Sequence Number : increasing integer
```

Here, clip_int is incremented whenever the clipboard changes, so you could create a listener function that checks to see if it's equal to the previous value or not.

Comment: by listener function do you mean a while true loop?

Comment: I think it will work though.